# Why addCylinder function not respecting the given coordinates?

Tags: mesh-generation, gmsh

I tried to generate 3 very simple cylinders, each other connected to it end, however the cylinder get connected to an unexistent point in space as the image shows:

[image]

It was supposed to each segment be 45º, 90º and 60º of inclination.

The code:

```
#include <gmsh.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    gmsh::initialize();
    gmsh::option::setNumber("General.Terminal", 1);
    gmsh::model::add("t1");

    double lc = 1e-2;

    gmsh::model::occ::addPoint(0, 0, 0, lc, 0);
    gmsh::model::occ::addPoint(0.35, 0.35, 0, lc, 1);
    gmsh::model::occ::addPoint(0.35, 1.35, 0, lc, 2);
    gmsh::model::occ::addPoint(0.85, 2.21, 0, lc, 3);


    gmsh::model::occ::addCylinder(0, 0, 0, 0.35, 0.35, 0,       0.05f, -1);
    gmsh::model::occ::addCylinder(0.35, 0.35, 0, 0.35, 1.35, 0, 0.05f, -1);
    gmsh::model::occ::addCylinder(0.35, 1.35, 0, 0.85, 2.21, 0, 0.05f, -1);

    gmsh::model::occ::synchronize();
    gmsh::model::mesh::generate(3);
    gmsh::write("t1.msh");
    gmsh::finalize();


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should ask this on the gmsh specific forums.

Comment: Did once, got no answer.

Comment: The problem is that the people with gmsh knowledge who hang out here are, at best, a subset of those who hang out at the gmsh forums. If they don't respond there, they're unlikely to respond here.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth not necessarily true. I don't read gmsh forums/maillist except when I google something. It is debatable where it is best to ask a certain question first. One can certainly qualify GMSH as a niche software, and then it is off-topic, but those questions are often answered here, as lots of people use GMSH.

Comment: @AntonMenshov, I think that was a Meta discussion that never reached conclusion, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know gmsh, but I have an idea you could check.

How are the coordinates interpreted?
If the coordinates are $x$ $y$ $z$, shouldn't the second cylinder be straight upwards, length one?

```
0,35 0,35 0    0,35, 1,35 0
```

Then the third cylinder would be correct.

All angles are absolute to the origin. Seeing only the image, it looks like you are off by the same value the first cylinder has.